# Select the first enabled option in a select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How could I set the value of a select element to the first enabled option?
Say I have html like this:

```
<select name="myselect" id="myselect">
    <option value="val1" disabled>Value 1</option>
    <option value="val2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="val3" disabled>Value 3</option>
    <option value="val4">Value 4</option>
</select>
```

How could I select the first option which isn't disabled (here it would be val2)?

Comment: Are the select options dynamically generated?

Comment: Most browsers would do this automatically wouldn't they? (Chrome, FF, and IE10 do.)

Comment: @LloydBanks Assume the select options are dynamically generated on the server side.

Comment: @nnnnnn Assume the disabled attribute could change.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this selecting the first option that is enabled.

```
$('#myselect').children('option:enabled').eq(0).prop('selected',true);
```

`.children()` for finding the list of option that is enabled , `.eq(0)` choosing the first entry on the list and using `.prop()` to select the option

Comment: Will this work if there are options that are not immediate children, like options in optgroup ?

Comment: @k-den no, in the document it says "only travels a single level down the DOM tree"